# Ajax call servlet and pass a ArrayList via Gson, display the list on html using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm currently studying how to ajax call servlet and pass an ArrayList via Gson, display the list on HTML using javascript

Here is the learning code I got from the internet --- [Sample code](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-request-response-java.html)

 I have some questions about it if the response data is a list, how we display it via javascript.

Here is the sample for display a single object response

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: "search",
            data: {"name":name, "indicator":indicator, "price":price, "location":location},
            dataType: "json",
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            $('#test').show();
            if(data.success){
                $("#ajaxResponse").html("");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<div class ='counter' data-countdown=" + data.itemsInfo.time + "></div>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<div><img src=" + data.itemsInfo.url + "></div>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<div class='description' ><p>Name:" + data.itemsInfo.name + "<br><br> Price:$" + data.itemsInfo.price+ "<br><br>Location" + data.itemsInfo.location 
                    +"Description:" + data.itemsInfo.description + "</p></div></c:forEach>");
                }
                else {
                    $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>No result found!!!</b></div>");
                }
            }
        });
```

Will these `data.itemsInfo.size()`,`data.itemsInfo.get(0).name` works here?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem related to the code discussed on the page you are referring to??

Comment: @fvu please see the js part from that article link